# How can I delete these phantom folders?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, user-folders

I have two folders on my desktop that have no name. If you right click them they have no properties and limited options. If I press delete, then they go but a moment later they reappear. I can move them around on the desktop and they stay where I put them. Pressing F2 to rename them does nothing.

How can I get rid of them?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to reboot?  Most of the time when files or folders exist in a weird state it's an indicate of a file system problem.

Comment: Open the Desktop folder with Explorer and look for these folders. Find all the information you can about them and add to the post.

Comment: @harrymc they don’t appear when viewed in explore.

Comment: @Ramhound a reboot which installed some windows updates appears to have fixed the issue! Never occurred to me that something so simple might fix it. Cheers.